# Finding Matrix of Linear Transformation without formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

We are given $[T]_\beta ^\gamma = \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$. We are also given that $\beta= \{sin^2x, cos^2x\}$ and $\gamma= \{1,sin^2x-1\}$. We want to find $[T]_\gamma ^\beta$. However, we aren't given a formula for the linear transformation, so I'm not sure how to start this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In general, when $\;\alpha,\beta\;$ basis of a vector space, we have that

$$[T]^\beta_\alpha=\left([T]_\beta^\alpha\right)^{-1}$$

Observe that a linear map (or matrix) mapping a basis to a basis is always an isomorphism (in finite dimensions)